# Suppressing Paragraph Numbers in LawTex

Tags: numbering, paragraphs, legal-style

I am using the LawTex package, arbitration class.  I am trying to edit the final page but I need to remove the paragraph numbers that are automatically put in place. Essentially, on the last page I want paragraphs that aren't numbered like the rest of the document. 
The package can be found here. http://sourceforge.net/projects/lawtex/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can issue

```
\endparano
```

wherever you want the paragraph numbering to stop.